# Submitting Long Query String with Mid Function - Getting Error and String is Truncated

Tags: asp-classic

I have a page where the user can select a lot of check boxes, and then have each of the values they select get inserted into a database.  I'm using a querystring to submit the values from the inital page to a post page.

The values are pipe-delimited, and the stored procedure runs for every one of them. I also have an integer I submit to the database as well.

A couple problems - first of all, on occasion I get a mid "invalid procedure call" error.  And other times, it seems I am submitting way too many characters for the QueryString and so it gets truncated and not all the values get submitted.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

The main page that submits the values - Javascript:

```
function submit()
{
    var n = 0;
    var stringIDs = "";

              //Number of records to submit stored in hidden text box.
    for (n=1; n<=parseInt(document.getElementById("txtResultsIndex").value); n++)
        {
            try
            {
                var cb = document.getElementById("cbSelection"+n);
                if (cb.checked) 
                    {
                        stringIDs = stringIDs + "|" + document.getElementById("linkNumber"+n).innerText;
                    }
            }

            catch(exception)
            {}
        }


window.open("submit.asp?stringIDs=" + stringIDs + "|&cboResearchedBy=" + document.getElementById("cboResearchedBy").value);

}
```

The post page classic ASP (where the error seems to be originating):

```
    Dim vSQLInsert, v1ID, RS, stringIDs, cboResearchedBy, CN

'GetDataConnection is included in header file.
Set CN = GetDataConnection

stringIDs = Request.QueryString("stringIDs")
cboResearchedBy = Request.QueryString("cboResearchedBy")

stringIDs = Mid(stringIDs,2,len(stringIDs)) 

Do While stringIDs <> ""
    v1ID = Mid(stringIDs,1,InStr(stringIds,"|")-1)

    'Insert data into main table.  
    vSQLInsert = "spInsert "    
    vSQLInsert = vSQLInsert & "@vResearchedBy = '" & cboResearchedBy & "',"
    vSQLInsert = vSQLInsert & "@vSequenceNumber = '" & v1ID & "'"       

    Set RS = CN.Execute (vSQLInsert)

    stringIDs = Replace(stringIDs, v1ID & "|","")
Loop
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. You could show a reproduction of the error, which will help make your question a better fit for StackOverflow. As to the truncation - if you have access to the source code, re-write the logic to do a regular FORM POST, instead of this javascript hack.

Comment: Internet Explorer has a limit to the length of a URL of around 2000 characters. Is your querystring (and URL) likely to be longer than that? If so you will have to rewrite to POST instead of GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Mid function.  Place values in a text box to submit to the post page in an array, using a for each loop.  Page still takes some time to submit, but no errors result.

vIndex = stripquotes(Request.Form("txtIndex"))

If Request.Form("cboResearchedBy") <> "" Then
    vResearchedBy = stripquotes(Request.Form("cboResearchedBy"))
End If

If Request.Form("txtMySeq") <> "" Then
    txtMySeq = Request.Form("txtMySeq")
End If

vSeqArray = Split(txtMySeq, "|")

For Each vSeq In vSeqArray

```
vSQLInsert = "Insert "  
vSQLInsert = vSQLInsert & "@vResearchedBy = '" & vResearchedBy & "',"
vSQLInsert = vSQLInsert & "@vSequenceNumber = '" & vSeq & "'"   

Response.Write(vSQLInsert)

Set RS = CN.Execute (vSQLInsert)
```

Next